# Request Mapping not working in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, controller, request-mapping

I have developed a simple web page using Spring Boot and I ma using combination of Class and Method Level Request Mapping Annotation but its not working under the below scenario.

Working when i hit http://localhost:9999/products
Not working when i hit http://localhost:9999/home/products

Controller Class:
    package com.example.demo;

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value= {"/","/home/"})
public class MainController {

@RequestMapping(value = {"products"},method=RequestMethod.GET)

public String index()
{
    return "Home.html";
}

}
```

Comment: What is the error that you receive? set the log level to debug and check the URL mapping, you should see a row that confirm the mapping  of you URL to the index() function.

Comment: Can you share your application.properties and View Resolver mapping..

Comment: Please post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Error I am receiving                                                                                               Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: Application.properties file has only one entry i.e server.port=9999

Answer (score 0):

> @RequestMapping(value= {"/","home"})

Comment: I don't think removing / would have any impact @harsh

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have your controller class with the same package or in the child package of your main Spring boot application class with annotation @SpringBootApplication, it seems then only it would scan your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Below should work..

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value= "/home")
public class MainController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/products",method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public String index()
   {
      return "Home.html";
   }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add @RestController annotation above your class name.